# VTiger 6 retrieve Sales Order products details

Tags: php, vtiger

Upon creating a custom module for Vtiger 6 (named Dispatch), I need to be able to automatically create a new Dispatch record every time a Sales Order is placed.

I'm extending the `SalesOrder_Record_Model` (modules/SalesOrder/models/Record.php) with the following:

```
public function save() {

        parent::save();

        Dispatch::NewFromSalesOrder($this);//static method to create the Dispatch new record from the Sales Order

}
```

So far so good.
The problem starts when I am trying to get the detailed product info of the Sales Order.

From my `Dispatch` class:

```
public static function NewFromSalesOrder($so) {

        $data = $so->getData();//gets the general data of the sales order, works fine!

        $products = $so->getProducts();//only gives me pricing and taxes, no product details

        //Also tried but same result 
        $products = getAssociatedProducts();//helper method from (include/utils/EditViewUtils.php)

}
```

So both methods only give me the pricing and tax info but no actual product data such as id/name/list price/comments, which is actually the only thing I need for the Dispatch module.

This is a var_dump of `$sales_order->getProducts()` after entering 3 products correctly.

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["final_details"]=> array(18) { ["taxtype"]=> NULL ["discount_type_final"]=> string(10) "percentage" ["hdnSubTotal"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["discount_percentage_final"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["discount_amount_final"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["checked_discount_percentage_final"]=> string(8) " checked" ["style_discount_percentage_final"]=> string(27) " style="visibility:visible"" ["style_discount_amount_final"]=> string(26) " style="visibility:hidden"" ["discountTotal_final"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["taxes"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(4) "tax1" ["taxlabel"]=> string(3) "VAT" ["percentage"]=> string(5) "4.500" ["amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" } [1]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(4) "tax2" ["taxlabel"]=> string(5) "Sales" ["percentage"]=> string(6) "10.000" ["amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" } [2]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(4) "tax3" ["taxlabel"]=> string(7) "Service" ["percentage"]=> string(6) "12.500" ["amount"]=> string(4) "0.00" } } ["tax_totalamount"]=> float(0) ["shipping_handling_charge"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["sh_taxes"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(6) "shtax1" ["taxlabel"]=> string(3) "VAT" ["percentage"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["amount"]=> float(0) } [1]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(6) "shtax2" ["taxlabel"]=> string(5) "Sales" ["percentage"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["amount"]=> float(0) } [2]=> array(4) { ["taxname"]=> string(6) "shtax3" ["taxlabel"]=> string(7) "Service" ["percentage"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["amount"]=> float(0) } } ["shtax_totalamount"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["adjustment"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["grandTotal"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["preTaxTotal"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["totalAfterDiscount"]=> string(4) "0.00" } } }
```

Am I missing something or calling the wrong method? Is there another method to retrieve the product details?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S I know I can query the database directly but Vtiger is horrible enough as a developer (poorly documented, bad design patterns, etc etc) even without me messing around with the queries, so I'd rather stick with their own OOP methods.

Comment: I have same frustrations with Vtiger. I am interested in this Dispatch module...can you share our collaborate?